# How do you get yakuake to show up when tabbing?

Tags: 18.04, yakuake

Given that a user is using super+tab keys to see running applications,
When the overlay modal is presented,
Then how do you configure yakuake to be included in the icon set. It is currently only available via a hot key.

Ubuntu: 18.04